# Delete linked list element saving the data

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I need to do a function to delete the last node from a linked list and return the data of the node. The prototype must be like the one in the following code.

```
struct no
{
    float number;
    struct no* next;
};

float delete(struct no**);


float delete(struct no** p)
{
    float number;
    struct no* temp=*p;
    while (*p) {
        p=&((*p)->next);
    }
```

All I did was make p point to the last pointer of the list. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: _All I did was make p point to the last pointer of the list._ Make it point to the next-to-last element in the list (if there is one). But don't modify `p` if that is the main pointer to the linked list.

Comment: What. is. the. question. ?.

Answer (score 3):

For starters it should be assumed that if the function is called for an empty list then the behavior is undefined because there is nothing to return. Otherwise the function prototype should be changed.

The function (as you declared it) can look the following way

```
float delete( struct no** p )
{
   while ( ( *p )->next != NULL ) p = &( *p )->next;

   float number = ( *p )->number;

   free( *p );

   *p = NULL;

    return number;
}
```

A more safe function can look the following way

```
int delete( struct no** p, float *number )
{
   int success = *p != NULL;

   if ( success )
   { 
       while ( ( *p )->next != NULL ) p = &( *p )->next;

       *number = ( *p )->number;

       free( *p );

       *p = NULL;
    }

    return success;
}
```